# how to select values on vector2 vales based on values on vector1

Tags: matlab

I'm using matlab and wanted to select vales on vector 2 based on vales of vector1.

Let say that vector 1 below present temperature and vector 2 present flow rate. 
What I wanted is that to select flow rate vales based flow temperature. For example, I wanted to find out how much volume of water (vector2) has been drawn at certain temperature range (i.e from 54 - 56 cel). In other words, I want to find out how much volume (the flow rates on vector2) has been drawn based on certain temperate ranges on vector1 (i.e 2 degree celcius temperature ranges: 44-46; 46-48; 48-50; 50 -52; 52-54; 54-56).

```
vec1    vec2
55.5    1.3
55.5    1.3
54.3    1.2
54.2    1.1
55.5    0
55.5    0
55.5    1.2
50.4    0.74
51.4    0.75
50.5    0.93
45.6    0
45.6    0
45.6    1.47
45.6    1.48
45.6    0.75
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Kind regards,
D Marini

Comment: What would the output be in this example, exactly? And how are ranges defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can separate your data into categories using `histc` then you can apply a function (a sum in this case) according to each created categories using `accumarray`:

```
data = [55.5    1.3
55.5    1.3
54.3    1.2
54.2    1.1
55.5    0
55.5    0
55.5    1.2
50.4    0.74
51.4    0.75
50.5    0.93
45.6    0
45.6    0
45.6    1.47
45.6    1.48
45.6    0.75];

[~,cat] = histc(data(:,1),44:2:56);
sumcat  = accumarray(cat,data(:,2)); %by default the applied function is a sum, so no need to specify the function.
```

**RESULT:**

```
sumcat =

    3.7000 %[44-46[         46 not included.
         0 %[46-48[
         0 %...
    2.4200
         0
    6.1000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your suggestion seems to work ok (at least for the given data). Will try to implement it for large data sets. Much appreciated your help.

Comment: Trying to implement your code for large data sets. I'm getting the following error: Error using accumarray
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.                     The first rows looks like below and my interesting vectors are vec2 and vec4:                                                                                                   
0                                         20 20                                0
0.000277777777777778  20 20                                0
any idea why this error happening? thanks

Comment: Have you understand how work the code above ? Of course you need to adjust your binrange (in `histc`) to your new data. Else the `cat` vector will only contain some 0. The above code is just an example.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had to extend the bin ranges and it works ok (thought that is something to do with decimal numbers)   many thanks, DMarini